# f(x)=exp(-x^2/2)(x^2-1) using PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

I am trying to graph a function using PGFPlots

f(x)=\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})(x^2-1)

my code is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin = -8, xmax = 8,
ymin = -2, ymax = 3,xtick distance = 2.5,
ytick distance = 0.5,
grid = both,
minor tick num = 1,
major grid style = {lightgray},
minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
width = \textwidth,
height = 0.5\textwidth,
]
\addplot[smooth,
thick,
blue,] exp(-x^2/2)(x^2-1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

what I get is

[image]

instead of

[image],

please help me...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I get is an error, actually. When plotting a function of x you should do

```
\addplot {<function>};
```

or

```
\addplot [<option>] {<function>};
```

if you're adding any options to the plot. You have done just `\addplot [...] <function>;` without the `{}`.

In addition, note that multiplication has to be specified explicitly with `*`, so you need

```
\addplot[smooth, thick,blue,] {exp(-x^2/2)*(x^2-1)};
```

Looking at the screenshot from Overleaf, I'd suspect you just forgot the `*`. With the above `\addplot`, I get

[image]

By default the domain plotted is `-5:5`, that's why the graph stops where it does. Add `domain=-8:8` to either the `axis` options or the `\addplot` options if you want to plot the function to the axis limits you have specified.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}   
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin = -8, xmax = 8,
ymin = -2, ymax = 3,xtick distance = 2.5,
ytick distance = 0.5,
grid = both,
minor tick num = 1,
major grid style = {lightgray},
minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
width = \textwidth,
height = 0.5\textwidth,
]
\addplot[smooth,
thick,
blue,] {exp(-x^2/2)*(x^2-1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks it helps@Torbjørn T.

Comment: Even if `x^2` now works for negative x, it is still bad practice (use `x*x`).